# Configuration of server required to create 1 TB tweet Lucene index

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene, cloud, elasticsearch

I want to collect tweets and store them in a Lucene index using twitter streaming api.The maxm size of solr index will be 2 TB.
Then I want to create a web interface which queries index and returns results in a file.The web server used is ApacheTomcat7 (running on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit/64 bit).
I want the response time of less than 1 second for quering and retrieval of data.

What should be the configuration of my server for this requirement?Should changing to Elastic Search will help?Should I need to migrate to cloud computing then what should be its configuration i.e how much computers with how much capacity?I do not know much about cloud computing?

Pls help

Comment: Elasticsearch requires a lot of heap size for managing large data volumes. Hence be prepared. Around 1 GB heap size for 10 M records on average.

Comment: 1 second is not very ambitious and a TB is not that much, depending on the query. You could probably run this on a laptop with a big usb drive and still get away with it. Solr and ES both use lucene and will largely run into the same bottlenecks for this. The easiest is to just try it and see what happens. ES is sharding and replicating out of the box, so probably the easiest to get started with. What matters is not the size of your source data but the size of your indexes and the number of documents in your data.